# Some properness condition in simplicial sets

Tags: simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Suppose that $C \to D$ is a trivial Kan fibration, and $D' \to D$ is an equivalence of simplicial sets. Let $C'$ be their pullback. Is it true that $C' \to D'$ is an equivalence?

Recall that a trivial Kan fibration is an equivalence.
It is then sufficient to show that $C' \to C$ is an equivalence, i.e. that equivalences pulled back along fibrations are equivalences. Indeed, by 2-3 property would follow that $C' \to C \to D$, $D' \to D$ equivalences $\Rightarrow $ $C' \to D'$ equivalence.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a lot simpler: trivial Kan fibrations are stable under pullback (they are defined by a lifting condition), so $C'→D'$ is a trivial Kan fibration, hence an equivalence.

Comment: What the hell! You are right. I should downvote myself XD